# Call specific tab on edit form in custom module in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I created one custom module in magento.When i click on the grid it moves to edit form where i can see three tabs like tab1,tab2,tab3.By default tab1 is selected.Now i want to add one link on grid and when customer click on that link browser redirect user to the tab3.How can i do that.My tab code as follow :

```
protected function _beforeToHtml()
  {
      $this->addTab('form_section', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Information'),
          'title'     => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Information'),
          'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule_edit_tab_form')->toHtml(),
      ));

     $this->addTab('form_section1', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__(' Management'),
          'title'     => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Management'),
          'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule_edit_tab_managment')->toHtml(),
      ));
          $this->addTab('form_section2', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Results'),
          'title'     => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Results'),
          'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule_edit_tab_result')->toHtml(),
      ));


      return parent::_beforeToHtml();
  }
```

My link code like that one on grid listing page. `<a class="viewit" href="http://localhost/project/index.php/mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule/view/id/4/key/83063e416ef7f9cfb7825d01e4519293/">View</a>`.My contoller function as:

```
 public function viewAction()
    {
     $this->loadLayout();
       $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule_edit_tab_result');
      //  $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule_edit_tab_result'))
            //->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule_edit_tabs'));
       $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);  
       $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code at [Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs::addTab](https://github.com/varinen/solvingmagento_1.7.0/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php#L141) suggests that tabs have property `active`. Try adding it to your `addTab` call:

```
$this->addTab('form_section2', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Results'),
          'title'     => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Results'),
          'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule_edit_tab_result')->toHtml(),
          'active'    => true
      ));
```

Or you can extend your Grid's row URLs with parameter `activeTab` set to 'form_section2' (the name of the active tab) and add the following code to the `_beforeToHtml` function of the `Tabs` block class:

```
        $param = Mage::app()->getRequest()->get('activeTab');
        if (array_key_exists($param, $this->_tabs)) {
            $this->_tabs[$param]->setActive();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but it comes every time with form_section2 selected either i click on link3 (for tab3) or link1 (for tab1).Can i pass "active" from controller ?

Comment: Sorry i update my question.Now you can see my controller.When i use comments code it show gettype error while on above code it show no left bar for tabs ?

Comment: I solve problem with this code.   if (array_key_exists($param, $this->_tabs)) {
              $this->addTab('form_section2', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Results'),
          'title'     => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__(' Results'),
          'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule_edit_tab_result')->toHtml(),
           'active'    => true
      ));
        }.I put this code in tab page at the end of addtab code and it works.Thanks for your direction and answer